# Build an index for substring search?

Tags: full-text-indexing

I want to do general substring search among billions of strings. The requirement is a little different from general fulltext search because I want a query "ubst" also can hit "substr".

Is Lucene or Sphinx capable of doing this? If not, what's the best way do you think to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Best index structure for this case is [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)
Lucene does not implements this type of index so its substring search is slow. But lucene has prefix tree index which mean you can do fast search if you search terms by their prefix.

Comment: Thanks. I've built a suffix array myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) does support effective substring searches since Version 2.0.1-beta, 22 apr 2011. Unfortunately as of today this support regards only beta versions, as mentioned [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=10451).

I made a try with 2.1.1 beta version. It seems to work correctly. See the [manual entry](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/conf-dict.html) for dictionary type, read about `keywords` type.

When I tried to use 2.0.6 release version, it fell back to inefficient crc index, giving the following warning during indexing:

```
WARNING: min_infix_len is not supported yet with dict=keywords; using dict=crc
```

My minimal configuration file:

```
source sour
{
  type = xmlpipe2
  xmlpipe_command = type C:\Temp\1\sphinx\input.xml
}

index inde
{
  source = sour
  path = testpa
  enable_star = 1
  dict = keywords
  charset_type = utf-8
  min_infix_len = 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lucene is one of the best available options. Lucene supports sub string search so ubst will return substr.

check out http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneImplementations for suitable language implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that Lucene doesn't have index on that.